# Regex for durations (HH:MM) and splitting? (Or built in C# Splitter)?

Tags: c#, regex, validation, split

I am trying to parse a string against the following format: HH:MM

```
12:23 //Normal
2:24 //No trailing 0
01:00 //With trailing 0
00:21 //00 First number
0:32 //0 First Number
10:4 //No 0 second number, denotes 10:04
```

First number max 24, min 0.

Second number max 59, min 0.

I made the string regex string `\d+:\d+`. But this still matches numbers outside of the ranges. What is the best way of handing these numbers?

I am doing this validation as a string in C#, if there is a better way of validating this format (and splitting it into hours and minutes, please let me know!)

Basically I am accepting the input as HH:MM, validating it, splitting it and then converting it into an `int` of minutes.

Example:

1. User enters 10:20
2. Checks format validation `HH:MM`
3. Checks range validation `(0-24):(0-60)`
4. Splits into variables `int hrs = 10` and `int mins = 20`
5. `return (mins + (hrs*60));`

Comment: `(0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]):(0?[0-9]|[1-5][0-9])`?

Comment: `var isGood = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(testValue, @"h\:m", null, out ts);`  but this would fail for 24 as an hour if you really encounter that.

Comment: Note that you actually want to support all of these [formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx): `H:m`, `HH:m`, `H:mm`, and `HH:mm`. A non-regex way is: `var fmts = new List<string>() { "H:m", "HH:m", "H:m", "HH:mm" };` `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("0:32", fmts.ToArray(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));`

Comment: All of your examples are easily parsed by `TimeSpan.Parse`: `new[]{"12:23","2:24","01:00","00:21","0:32","10:4"}.Select(TimeSpan.Parse)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TimeSpan.TryParse`. This has the added benefit of calculating the minutes for you via the `TotalMinutes` property:

```
List<string> tests = new List<string>()
{
    "12:23", //Normal
    "2:24", //No trailing 0
    "01:00", //With trailing 0
    "00:21", //00 First number
    "0:32", //0 First Number
    "10:4", //No trailing 0 second number
};

foreach (var test in tests)
{
    TimeSpan t;
    if (TimeSpan.TryParse(test, out t))
        Console.WriteLine(t.TotalMinutes);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Not valid");
}
```

Which outputs:

> 743
>   144
>   60
>   21
>   32
>   604

@AlexK correctly points out in the comments that this will match strings that include seconds such as `11:22:33`. To prevent that you can use `TryParseExact` and pass an array of acceptable formats:

```
List<string> tests = new List<string>()
{
    "12:23", //Normal
    "2:24", //No trailing 0
    "01:00", //With trailing 0
    "00:21", //00 First number
    "0:32", //0 First Number
    "10:4", //No trailing 0 second number
    "11:22:33", //Error
};

foreach (var test in tests)
{
    TimeSpan t;
    //if (TimeSpan.TryParse(test, out t))
    if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(test, new[] { "h\\:m", "hh\\:m", "hh\\:m", "h\\:mm", "hh\\:mm" }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out t))
        Console.WriteLine(t.TotalMinutes);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Failed");
}
```

Which outputs

> 743
>   144
>   60
>   21
>   32
>   604
>   Failed

Comment: This would also pass a tri-part string "11:22:33"

Comment: Had just prepared a code example to this end. The right answer.

Comment: Isn't 604 wrong for the last result? He says 10:4 should have a trailing zero indicating it's 10:40, not 10:04.

Comment: @Equalsk Sorry, I mistyped- 10:4 should indicate 10:04

Comment: D'oh! I was going to post about TimeSpan and was busy looking at a way to solve the 10:40 problem... Oh well!

Comment: @Equalsk - luckily I misread Bitz' mistyping and read what he actually meant which was lucky. You are right, against the original requirement this wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @AlexK. - you're quite right, this will allow more through than is strictly required. I've edited to include a way to exclude those.

Comment: Thank you, this solution- the second one- works perfectly! I was just about to write a comment about converting unvalidated inputs (whole numbers into days) as well as accepting seconds. 
Your edit fixed the shortcomings of the first solution! 
Awesome! 
(Though- now I feel bad for those who come to this question hoping to find a regex solution, haha)